# Single Java implementation of zip with multiple compression methods

Tags: java, zip, compression, bzip2, lzma

For my assignment in Java I need to compare various compression methods (e.g. Deflate, Implode, BZIP2 and LZMA) while creating a zip file and compare their speed and zip file size. I did find seperate Java implementations for the above methods, but I'd like to have a single library for all methods, so that the different implementations wouldn't impact on the results (probably wouldn't make any difference either way but still).

So is there any Java library with source code, that supports multiple zip compression methods?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at [Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/)? This library supports `ar, cpio, Unix dump, tar, zip, gzip, XZ, Pack200, bzip2, 7z, arj, lzma, snappy, DEFLATE and Z files` and seems to match with your needs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thank you and seanoftime for the link, it looked quite promising. After tinkering around and reading their documentation, their Zip implementation only supports Deflate and offer other compression methods separately by compressing a single file (e.g. tar file) and not in zip itself, which is what I'm after.

Comment: That will still allow you to compare speed and size for the various compression methods.  The zip file wrapper around the compressed data is entirely inconsequential to both speed and size.

Comment: Oh yes I am aware that the zip file wrapper can easily be neglected regarding speed and size, but my assignment demands on testing exclusively zip files with different compression methods as it'll be a part of an automatic testing system.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apache Commons Compress might be what you're looking for:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/